# Passenger stalls with helper process on application start

Tags: passenger, passenger-nginx

The following error is being returned after a system restart (there was a lack of memory issue) before the restart.

```
The Phusion Passenger application server tried to start the web application by communicating with a helper process that we call a "preloader". However, this helper process sent a response that looks like gibberish.

The response is as follows:
```

The response is a blank.  Although it is suggested to fill out a bug report, I do not suspect this to be a bug, as everything was working previously.  the only diagnostics provided indicate:

```
PID 1554
x  Receive and process preloader response — 0.4s
```

What can be done about this?

Answer (score 1):

A server re-start fixes the issue.  Satisfactory outcome, unsatisfactory motive...